# Any thoughts on how Warren Buffet's B of A warrants might be "marked-to-market" by either counterparty?

Tags: options, option-pricing

It's not too long since Berkshire Hathaway got its 10-year warrants in Bank of America alongside its \$5 billion purchase of preferred stock.  At the time I saw some discussion about the value of these 700,000,000 "free" warrants (exercisable at \$7.13) as being worth up to 65% of B of A's stock price which was about \$7 at the time.  So, the argument went that for his \$5,000,000,000 Berkshire got \$5,000,000,000 of redeemable preferred and \$3,185,000,000 worth of warrants.

I have looked to see how both Berkshire Hathaway and Bank of America may be carrying the respective assets and liabilities regarding these warrants and can't find it in their financials.

This isn't a heavy quant question, but I would welcome any insight.  Thanks

Comment: Surely Black-Scholes will give you a reasonable answer, if you factor in 10y interest rates?

Comment: this might be worth posting here http://www.wilmott.com/categories.cfm?catid=41